# Automatically setting a cookie's attribute to SameStite=None in Chromium/Chrome

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, cookies, chromium

I'm using a react app to run some code in development.

Currently, my startup script looks like this:

```
"start:browser": "open -n -a /Applications/Chromium.app --args --user-data-dir='/tmp/chromium_dev_test' --disable-web-security --disable-popup-blocking",
```

But, I have to manually set one of my cookies in the browser to SameSite: None.

I would prefer to do this in the startup script. Is there a way to add this to the above command? I don't mind setting it to all the cookies used automatically.

Comment: Please explain why you think you need to do this. Also it's your server that tells your browser to set that attribute.

Comment: If I don't do this, Chrome cannot set the cookie once I've authenticated, and my site crashes with endless redirects trying to authenticate and then set the cookie.

Comment: Okay, but again it is your server that sets that attribute, chrome itself can't do this. But that seems to be a problem of your application not handling the authentication process correctly, not an issue with chrome.

Comment: Please provide the relevant bits of code as well as possible error messages you see. This question could just be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676/364724).

Comment: This command: open -n -a /Applications/Chromium.app --args --user-data-dir='/tmp/chromium_dev_test' --disable-web-security --disable-popup-blocking
is the only bit of code, I just want the cookie to have the attribute SameSite:None automatically set, instead of me having to go into the chrome webinspector, and set it after I've authenticated

Comment: Are you aware that it is your development server that sets the `SameSite` attribute when providing the `Set-Cookie` header? Chrome can't do that for you and you can't and shouldn't try to automate that manual process of doing what you described. Instead you should check why your server doesn't set that attribute. Which server framework and authentication backend are you using? How did you setup your project? Please take a step back from your approach as it will not lead anywhere.

Comment: okay, thanks for the advice, will look into the backend